# Create a MS Dev Box with API

Tags: javascript, azure, rest, oauth-2.0, azure-dev-box

I have currently problems with the token for the MS Dev Center service.

I call the REST API `PUT {endpoint}/projects/{projectName}/users/{userId}/devboxes/{devBoxName}?api-version=2023-04-01` with a Bearer token like described:
[AAD Token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0bNM.png)

- I have the right authority.
- I have the right scope "user_impersonation"
- I use the implicit oauth2 flow

I successfully retrieved the token with the CLI:

`az account get-access-token --resource https://devcenter.azure.com`

but when I use the interactive flow in my react app, I get a 401.

Observations:

- The jwt token retrieved with the CLI is encrypted
- The browser "Try it" function under (https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/rest/api/devcenter/developer/dev-boxes/create-dev-box?view=rest-devcenter-developer-2023-04-01) is also not working, when I log in with the account which should be able to create a dev box. (401)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Microsoft documentation it says you need to use the [user_impersonation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIACO.png) scope.

I solved it by configuring the "Fidalgo Dataplane Public" API with "access_as_user" scope in my app registration.

[Fidalgo Dataplane Public](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXGXV.png)

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't exactly clear in your post but ensure you have the [Dev Box User Role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dev-box/quickstart-configure-dev-box-service?tabs=AzureADJoin#5-provide-access-to-a-dev-box-project) on the project with a Dev Box Pool.